# What would be the proper way to design the class hierarchy here?

Tags: java, class-design

I am writing a "hunting-ground" application in Java. I planned the hierarchy of classes as follows:

Animal.java

```
public interface Animal {

    void age();

    void reproduce();

    boolean isAlive();

    void die();
}
```

Carnivorus.java

```
public abstract class Carnivorus implements Animal {

    double age;
    double expectancy;
    boolean alive;

    abstract void hunt();
}
```

Herbivore.java

```
public abstract class Herbivore implements Animal{

    double age;
    double expectancy;
    boolean alive;

    abstract void graze();

}
```

Lion.java

```
public class Lion extends Carnivorus {


    Lion(double currentAge,double livesFor){

        age = currentAge;
        expectancy = livesFor;
        alive = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void reproduce() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void hunt() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void age() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        age--;

    }

    @Override
    public void die() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        alive = false;

    }

    public boolean isAlive(){

        return alive;
    }


}
```

I noticed that the variable definitions in Carnivore and Herbivore are repeated. But since Animal is a interface, I can't define variables there. In case I changed the Animal to a abstract class and defined the variables there, the Carnivore and Herbivore interfaces can't extends it. What would be the proper way to design it ?

Comment: Things aren't always so neatly divided into categories.  See [When Bambi Ate Thumper](http://www.slate.com/articles/health_and_science/science/2012/11/deer_eat_meat_herbivores_and_carnivores_are_not_so_clearly_divided.html).  I mention this not to invalidate your design, which is presumably a textbook example, but to point out that inheritance hierarchies to model the real world should be viewed with a skeptical eye.

Comment: Interesting read. I will certainly take into account this variation of behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Yes - your problem is that the level that these animals share attributes is what should be an abstract class. You should be able to extend one abstract class with another abstract class though, like this:

Animal becomes an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Animal {

    double age;
    double expectancy;
    boolean alive;

    Animal(double currentAge,double livesFor) {
        age = currentAge;
        expectancy = livesFor;
        alive = true;
    }

    void age() {
        // TODO:
    }

    void reproduce() {
        // TODO:
    }

    boolean isAlive() {
        // TODO:
    }

    void die() {
        // TODO:
    }
}
```

Carnivorus then becomes:

```
public abstract class Carnivorus extends Animal {
    abstract void hunt();
}
```

and Herbivore is now:

```
public abstract class Herbivore extends Animal{
    abstract void graze();
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! I got it wrong as I had understood that if an abstract class is extended, it should implement the abstract methods and did not think that child classes can be abstract as well.

Answer (score 1):

> But since Animal is a interface, I can't define variables there. In
>   case I changed the Animal to a abstract class and defined the
>   variables there, the Carnivore and Herbivore interfaces can't extends
>   it.

In your code **Carnivore and Herbivore are not interfaces but abstract classes so they could extend Animal** if you turned it into an abstract class.

In the other hand your Animal interface (if it was to remain as such) needs some methods that hint implementors of aditional state:

```
public interface Animal {
    void age();
    void reproduce();
    boolean isAlive();
    void die() throws AlreadyDeadException;
    public double getCurrentAge();
    public double getLifeExpentancy();
}
```

---

Comment: Upvote for your insight in throwing exception